# in mailto: replace subject and body adding %20 instead space in all file php using notepad++

Tags: php, regex, notepad++, space, mailto

Goodmorning, I have a question... I have a blog with mailto in each post/comment that contains subject and body but between the words there are blank space that I'd like replace with %20 for better validation html. Each mailto has a different subject and body and I'd like to replace using notepad++ regex matching only this kind of string:

```
<A HREF="mailto:pippo@pluto.it?subject=Diario: Tanto per ridere un p&ograve;...&amp;body=Gentile visitatore, La informo che messaggi offensivi o volgari verranno scartati, buona prosecuzione." CLASS="hyperlink">Pippo Pluto</A>

<A HREF="mailto:topolino@paperino.it?subject=Diario: Dead Space e Dead Sapce 2&amp;body=Gentile visitatore, La informo che messaggi offensivi o volgari verranno scartati, buona prosecuzione." CLASS="hyperlink">Paolino Paperino</A>
```

As result I'd like to have:

```
<A HREF="mailto:picodepaperis@dysney.it?subject=Diario:%20Neutrini%20sfondano%20i%20300.000%20Km/s&amp;body=Gentile%20visitatore,%20La%20informo%20che%20messaggi%20offensivi%20o%20volgari%20verranno%20scartati,%20buona%20prosecuzione." CLASS="hyperlink">De Paperis Pico</A>
```

I have 560 php files that contain the blank space and I'd like to process all files using a regular expression in Notepad++

I wrote this regex that finds only the mailto string, but does not cover the occurrence of blank space.

```
<A HREF=\"mailto:([^"]*)\" CLASS="hyperlink">
```

Is there a solution?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not doing this programatically?

Comment: from now is automatic using simple str_replace php but for old post I have to modify them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tweaked your Regex expression to include two more groups and create a `Find` String like this

```
<A HREF=\"mailto:([^"]*)(\s)(.*)\" CLASS="hyperlink">
```

and the `Replace` string should be like this

```
<A HREF=\"mailto:\1%20\3\" CLASS="hyperlink">
```

My idea is to capture  one occurance of a whitespace  and replacing it with `%20`. However When you apply `Replace All` inside notepad++(regular expression mode), it will replace only one space on all matching lines so you have to click on `Replace All` several times until the message says  `0 occurance was replaced`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)? Why don't you use that instead of adding the encoded string in your code?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using:    **<A HREF="mailto:' . $mail . '?subject=Diario:%20' . str_replace(' ', '%20', $topic) . '&amp;body=' . str_replace(' ', '%20', 'Gentile visitatore, La informo che messaggi offensivi o volgari verranno scartati, buona prosecuzione.') . '" CLASS="hyperlink">' . $name .  '</A>** but old post/comment don't have %20 in the space...

Comment: $subject and $body are processed by htmlentities so I have only to convert blank space with %20. I know urlencode and I don't need for my purpose, thanks anyway.

Comment: line 265 column 79 - warning: <a> escaping malformed URI reference
**<a href="http://www.mozilla.org/one space.html">space</a>** wrong
**<a href="http://www.mozilla.org/one%20space.html">space</a>** correct
Reported By Validation Firefox plugin HTML Tidy

Answer (score 0):

%20 is space, write space in your address line and click enter. there isn't a problem :)

Comment: I know tha %20 is a space but when I want to validate my url with html Tidy HTML Validator engine (SGML + Tidy) I obtain a warning because there are spaces " " between words while I have no warning when I use %20 between words... mailto:pulci@pulci.com?subject=This is wrong&amp;body=This is a test... while mailto:pulci@pulci.com?subject=This%20is%20correct%20&amp;body=This%20is%20a%20test...